# Adding Tag Data to File

Tags: linux, microsoft-excel, cat

For a security product (data loss prevention) my group is trying to tag files with specific keywords to allow for HR/Legal to specifically flag files for tracking by our DLP software. Currently the scope is limited to Office files and PDFs.

My supervisor suggested attaching strings on the end of the files, and he used a Terminal emulator. I believe he typed in:

> cat workbook.xlsx textToAppend.txt > workbookWithAppendedText.xlsx

...And then `cat`-ing workbookWithAppendedText.xlsx to the screen showed the appended text. "textToAppend.txt" is simply the phrase "simple text" and nothing more. I can repeat it thus far, and I can see the phrase "simple text" appended to the end.

However, then *he* was able to open the file, and it opened fine; no error message displayed, and the "simple text" was hidden. When I do it, however, I get the following error:

[image: Excel Error]

Excel is able to recover it, and in doing so it removes the text I appended. My supervisor has left the office so I can't reach out to him.

How can I reproduce the behavior my supervisor was able to produce?

Comment: Frankly, I cannot believe _he_ was able to open the file without errors after appending text to a binary file as an Excel workbook. Did you see that it worked for him or he just _told_ you? It seems to me he's pulling your leg.

Comment: @cdlvcdlv I watched him append and verify both that it was appended and he could open the file. I'm not absolutely sure what command he used (the above is what I recalled as I walked back to my desk). I don't recall any other step he took, he just created the append text file with an echo, and then combined the files.

Comment: My advice is you don't do that _cat_ thing. Both Office and PDF files include keyword fields you can use to categorize them.

Answer (score 0):

As [cdlvcdlv](https://superuser.com/users/607984/cdlvcdlv) says, you almost certainly don't want to do this - appending text to a `.xlsx` file is not going to work consistently (if at all) and is just not the way to do what you're trying to do.

`.xlsx` files are just a package of `XML` files, which technically can be extracted, edited and them re-packaged, but again, this is highly unlikely to be the best way to achieve your goal of adding tags to these files for categorization purposes.

Instead, Excel provides built-in functionality for adding tags to these files. Just open one in Excel and go to File -> Info and look for the Tags field in the Propoerties section:

[image: Excel Tags]

You can then view, sort and search on these tags in Windows Explorer:

[image: Excel Tags Explorer]

Alternatively, if your files are stored in a Document Management System like SharePoint, they usually offer their own tagging/categorization/metadata functionality, all of which would be better than trying to append text to the `.xlsx` itself.